# Disable live bindings at run time

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

I have a `TStringGrid` bind to a DataSet using `liveBindings`. I want in specific situations to disable the connection.
What is the proper way to achieve this at run time?

Comment: Live binding links have an active property available at runtime.

Comment: @Brian can you please specify how I actually access them at run time?
I Don't see it in the binding list and not in the binding source.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They are represented by the lines in the LiveBindings Designer and are called LinkXXXXtToYYYYY. At runtime you set properties for them like anything else : `LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1.active := false;`.